# How do I replace poorly formatted ZIP codes with proper ones?

Tags: sas

I have a data set that that looks like this:

```
adjuster  adjuster_zip

A-20       98216

A-14       98214

A-17       98216

A-20       California
```

I need to format this data set so that adjuster_zip is all numeric.  I have several hundred adjusters and they all show up several hundred times.  However, they each adjuster only has one zip code.  As you can see with A-20, this adjuster has both a valid and invalid zip code.  All of the adjusters that have invalid zip codes also have valid zip codes.  How can I automate this so that SAS switches invalid zip codes with valid ones by adjuster?

Thanks for any and all help.

Also, I couldn't figure out how to format the data so that it shows up in a table.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to build a format table per adjuster.  Start with your input dataset; then filter to only valid zip codes (you could use NOTDIGIT to check for any nondigit values, and LENGTH to check it is only five long).  Then create a dataset with `FMTNAME` as a constant string with any legal format name you wish preceded by $ (`$ADJZIPF` would be a good cohice), `START` equal to the variable that contains the adjuster name, `LABEL` being the zip.  Then use `PROC FORMAT` with `cntlin=` the dataset you just defined.

That would allow you to look up the zip for each adjuster using `PUT` and your custom format.  You still have to worry about a few things; that table must be non-duplicated per adjuster, so you need to decide how to handle adjusters with two or more zips; and you need to check when you use PUT that it does find a zip code.